# How to find the objective function of the dual problem

Tags: linear-programming

> Consider  the linear programming Problem: Maximize  $z= 2x_1 +3x_2 +x_3$ such that
>
> $4x_1+3x_2 + x_3=6$
>
> $x_1 + 2x_2 + 5x_3 \ge  4$
>
> $x_1, x_2 , x_3 \ge 0$
>
> Write  down the objective  function  of the dual problem

My attempt :  From $4x_1+3x_2 + x_3=6$  - $(1)$

$x_1 + 2x_2 + 5x_3 \ge  4$          -$(2)$

Multiply  $(2)$ with $4$ we have $4x_1 +8x_2 + 20x_3 =16$

Now $4x_1 +8x_2 + 20x_3 =16$ subtract  $4x_1+3x_2 + x_3=6$ we have $6x_2 +19x_3 =10$
After that im not able proceed further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the primal problem right hand sides, the objective of the dual problem is to minimize $6y_1+4y_2$.

Comment: How u got $ 6y_1+4y_2$? Can u elaborate more  @Rob

Comment: The primal is maximization, so the dual is minimization.  The primal has two constraints, so the dual has two variables, say $y_1$ and $y_2$, and their objective coefficients are the primal rhs values.  Because the first primal constraint is equality, $y_1$ is free.  Because the second constraint is $\ge$ in a maximization, $y_2\le 0$.